# R Shiny Ignore placeholder label/value filtering with selectInput

Tags: r, dplyr, shiny

UI

```
selectInput("marital_status", "Marital Status: ", choices = c("SELECT", setNames(marital_status$m_id,marital_status$m_name)))
```

Server

```
selected_members <- reactive(
    
      tmk %>% filter(between(AGE, input$age[1], input$age[2])) %>% 
        filter(between(ROOMS, input$room[1], input$room[2])) %>% 
        filter(between(PMT, input$pmt[1], input$pmt[2])) %>% 
        filter(MARITAL_STATUS %in% input$marital_status)
  )
```

Currently the last filter on MARITAL_STATUS results in 0 results in selected_memebers data frame as the selectInput returned value at input$marital_status initializes to "SELECT" when app is first run, is there any way the "placeholder"/"default" selection to be ignored from filter, I am not quite sure of exact format, any help would be greatly appreciated!

P.S: Code works fine with individual selections with MARITAL_STATUS input values/selections

Comment: I'm not sure if it would help, but when I've encountered something similar I've just made the reactive an ifelse. i.e ```reactive({if(input$marital_status == "SELECT") {tmk} else {tmk%>%filter(MARITAL_STATUS %in% input$marital_status) })```

Comment: you can use another reactiveVal that is first filled when the MARITAL_STATUS changes but not prior to that

Comment: @Silentdevildoll your suggestion seems not to work as intended, if(input$marital_status == "SELECT") 
    {tmk} 
    else 
    {tmk%>%filter(MARITAL_STATUS %in% input$marital_status)}
    
      tmk %>% filter(between(AGE, input$age[1], input$age[2])) %>% 
        filter(between(ROOMS, input$room[1], input$room[2])) %>% 
        filter(between(PMT, input$pmt[1], input$pmt[2])) ... this shows same number of records with placeholder and any other actual selections, did i miss something?

Comment: @mnist can you please elaborate, please note user can select "placeholder" / "SELECT" just to turn off marital status fitler or select any of its value from time to time

Comment: Can you provide `ui` and `server` code required for the question to be completely reproducible along with necessary data if required?

Comment: @RonakShah thank you, I just found a solution, as in answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is the correct syntax if you'd like "filter" to initally ignore the placeholder text and search only when user makes any valid selection (or back to placeholder text in that case it returns a larger dataset i.e. skipping the filter)

```
tmk %>% filter(between(AGE, input$age[1], input$age[2])) %>% 
        filter(between(ROOMS, input$room[1], input$room[2])) %>% 
        filter(between(PMT, input$pmt[1], input$pmt[2])) %>%
        {if(input$marital_status != "SELECT") filter(., MARITAL_STATUS == input$marital_status) else .}
```

Answer (score 0):

simply add a `req` on the first line inside your reactive. Remeber to wrap your expression in `reactive` with `{}`

```r
selected_members <- reactive({
    req(input$marital_status != "SELECT")
    tmk %>% filter ...
})
```

Comment: req(input$marital_status != "SELECT") ... this makes all filters turned off, is it possible for other filters to still work initially (ignoring marital_status filter) and return some rows i.e. larger dataset intially and smaller as user further selects further down